# Local variable created somehow regardless there's the global one

Tags: javascript

```js
var construct = function() {
  var self = this;

  var view = {
    name: "self"
  };

  self.vm = {
    attached: attached,
    view: view
  }

  function attached() {
    alert('view.name: ' + view.name);
    view = {
      name: "attached"
    };
    alert('view.name(after attached): ' + view.name);
    alert('self.vm.view.name: ' + self.vm.view.name);
    alert('this.view.name: ' + this.view.name);
  }

  self.vm.attached();

  return self.vm;
}()
```

As you can see, we have a variable 'view' in a global (related to selv.vm object) context.
view is passed by reference to the self.vm object.

Knowing this we can assume that 'attached' method will change the global variable and as a result self.vm.view will point to a new object.

A new local variable will be created regardeless there's the global with the same name.

A kinda unexpected behavior isn't it? Any ideas why so?

Comment: can you also write the values which are appearing on alert.

Comment: *"...and as a result self.vm.view will point to a new object."* that's incorrect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inside the `function attached()`, You are basically reassigning your `view` variable to a newly created object. You are not changing the existing object, the object is still there. And since `self.vm.view` holds the reference to the initial value of the `view`, you'll see those value when you do a `self.vm.view.name`.

If you want the change the value in original object you've to do a

```
view.name = "attached";
```

Answer (score 2):

To boil this down to a bare bones example:

```js
var a = {name: 'one'};
var b = {view: a};

// See what b.view holds
console.log(b.view);

// Change a and look again
a = {name: 'two'};
console.log(b.view);
```

We have changed the object which the reference `a` points to. But `b.view` still holds a reference to the original object (which `a` pointed to before it was reassigned)

Answer (score 1):

It's because `view` is a pointer.

```
var construct = function() {
  var self = this;

  // this create a new object, with the property name being "self"
  // and "view" as a pointer to that object
  var view = {
    name: "self"
  };

  self.vm = {
    attached: attached,
    // here the property "view" of the "vm" object points to the variable "view", which itself points to the original object (the one with name="self")
    view: view
  }

  function attached() {
    // the pseudo-global "view" object is called, it reaches out to the object it points to and gives us the name: "self"
    alert('view.name: ' + view.name);
    // now we are changing "view" to point to a NEW object, with the property name="attached"
    view = {
      name: "attached"
    };
    // view points to the new object, it's name is "attached"
    alert('view.name(after attached): ' + view.name);
    // the "view" property of self.vm still points to the original object, the one with the name "self"
    alert('self.vm.view.name: ' + self.vm.view.name);
    alert('this.view.name: ' + this.view.name);
  }

  self.vm.attached();

  return self.vm;
}()
```

Take a look at this question too: [Javascript by reference vs. by value](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6605640/855738). Maybe it can explain things better than I do.

It's a tricky subject.